# How to delete an instance of a Class in C++ using cin?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am new to programming, I  was working on a Student management program, the program can Add, Search, show a list of student names, but I cannot figure how to remove a name from the list. I am using a student structure and Vector to create different students using Console Input.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "stdio.h"
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct student
{
    int roll_no, clas;
    char name[20];

};

void get_input(vector<student>& p1, int n1)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++)
    {
        student s;
        cout << " Enter Roll Number: ";
        cin >> s.roll_no;
        cout << "\n Enter Name of the student: ";
        cin >> s.name;
        cout << "\n Enter Class of the Student ";
        cin >> s.clas;
        p1.push_back(s);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    int choice;
    int choice1;
    int choice2;
    string search;
    int search_no;
    vector<student> p;
    while (true) {
    start1:
        cout << "1.Student list \n";
        cout << "2.Add a Student to the list \n";
        cout << "3.Remove a Student from the list \n";
        cout << "4.Search \n";
        cin >> choice;
        switch (choice) {
        case 1:
            
            if (p.empty()) {
                cout << " List is Empty \n";
            }
            else {
                cout << "***Student List*** \n" << endl;
                for (auto& r : p) {
                
                    cout << " Roll no: " << r.roll_no << ", Name " << r.name << " Class: " << r.clas << endl;
                    
                }
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            cout << "How many student details would you want to enter: ";
            cin >> n;
            cout << endl;
            get_input(p, n);
            break;
        case 3:
            cout << "Enter the name of Student to be removed \n";
            break;
        case 4:
start2:
            cout << "1. Search by Name \n";
            cout << "2. Search by roll no. \n";
            cout << "3. Search by Class \n";
            cout << "4. Previous menu \n";
            while (true) {
                cin >> choice1;
                switch (choice1) {
                case 1:                 
                    cout << " Searching by name \n";
                    cout << "Enter the Studnet name you want to search " << endl;
                    cin >> search;
                    for (auto& r : p) {
                        if (r.name != search) {
                        }
                        else if (r.name == search) {
                            cout << " Roll no. : " << r.roll_no << ", Name " << r.name << endl;
                        }
                    }
                    cout << " Enter 4 to go back \n";
                    cin >> choice2;
                    if (choice2 == 4) {
                        goto start2;
                        
                    }
                    break;
                case 2:
                    cout << " Searching by roll no. \n";
                    cout << "Enter the roll no. you want to search " << endl;
                    cin >> search_no;
                    for (auto& r : p) {
                        if (r.roll_no != search_no) {
                        }
                        else if (r.roll_no == search_no) {
                            cout << " Roll no. : " << r.roll_no << ", Name " << r.name << endl;
                        }
                    }

                    cout << "Enter 4 to go back \n";
                    cin >> choice2;
                    if (choice2 == 4) {
                        goto start2;
                    }break;
                case 3:
                    cout << " Searching by class \n";
                    cout << "Enter the Class you want to search " << endl;
                    cin >> search_no;
                    for (auto& r : p) {
                        if (r.clas != search_no) {
                        }
                        else if (r.clas == search_no) {
                            cout << " Roll no. : " << r.roll_no << ", Name " << r.name << endl;
                        }
                    }
                    cout << "Enter 4 to go back \n";
                    cin >> choice2;
                    if (choice2 == 4 ) {
                        goto start2;
                    }break;
                case 4:
                    goto start1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I know one could use dynamic allocation and delete but not sure if thats the path to go.

Comment: Are you looking for how to [erase](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) an element?

Comment: Unrelated to your question but refactoring your code into more functions would likely help you avoid using `goto`

Comment: There are really two choices, the good way is to use the `vector::erase` method, but that will require that you learn about *iterators* which it appears you do not know about at present. The less good way is to move the student you want to erase to the end of the list (and move the other students up the list as well) and then call `vector::pop_back` to shorten your list by one student.

Comment: I was trying to implement Vector.erase but was not able to, after some research I was able to make it work. thank you guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an unordred_map, its a container of pairs of keys and values, you could use student names as key, you can access the students in order of 1, search, insertion and removal all are done in constant time.
Works like this:

```
std::unordred_map<std::string, struct student> map;
std::string stName;
int stClass;
int rollNo;
//insertion
std::cin >> stName >> stClass >> rollNo;
//use of student constructor here and it is assumed it is provided for your struct as such.
map.insert({stName, student(stClass, rollNo)};
//deletion
std::cin >> stName;
map.erase(stName);
//search
auto it0 = map.find(stName);
if(it0 != map.end()); //found otherwise not found, use it0->first/second to access the underlying data, first is your key, second is your value
//to traverse the container
for(auto it{map.begin()}; it != map.end(); ++it)
    std::cout << "name: " << it->first << " info: " << it->second.stClass;
```

Note that this seperation of associated data is not recommended, std::unordered_set is the better option here but that requires your type to be "hashable" and you have to provide hash_function for you data type but since that requires a bit more work and knowledge I would recommend using unordered_map here since unordered_map already knows how to hash std::string.

Also it is recommended to avoid using 'while(true)' and 'goto' statements in your code as it makes the code hard to understand, follow and error prone.

standard documentation: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map

Comment: Thank you, I will try to learn about map but its just a bit for me to grasp, I did used v.erase(); with some research and it is working at the moment and I understand that while(true) and goto could put the the program in a continuous loop but I am still learning and will try to improve.

Comment: I hope you found my code useful, and use of hash maps as well.